Impossible to translate string from webform
2.2 in a drupal 10 solution.
I am trying translate via the UI the following error that I can see at WebformElementBase.php
  $form_state->setError($element, t('The value %value sdsadad %name element. You may have already submitted this webform, or you need to use a different value.', $t_args));

I search both under admin/config/regional/translate and admin/structure/webform/config/advanced.
I have already loaded the page with the string so it should appear under translations if that was the case.

Are you sure thats the code from WebformElementBase.php? specifically this bit? sdsadad

I added that part to see if it would load in the UI so I know it is the correct string I am loading.

Assuming it is the right code (and the gibberish is something you've added to try and shake it into doing something), make sure you've actually seen this message in the front end, in the language you're trying to translate into. It won't be in the translation table until it's been first rendered

It has been rendered, maybe a bug in t(' function. _/

Maybe by adding sdsadad its removed the proper string from the translation interface. When you search for the string including sdsadad does that show? If so remove it, get the real string to appear again and clear the caches

Ok so the part that I missed was the on @Clive point out. It needs to be seen in the specific language.
Thanks! You wanna make it an answer and I'll accept it?

Assuming it is the right code (and the gibberish is something you've added to try and shake it into doing something), make sure you've actually seen this message in the front end, in the language you're trying to translate into.
It won't be in the translation table until it's been first rendered.
